# Select-string apply to multiple lines of input

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a file like:

```
abc WANT THIS
def NOT THIS
ghijk WANT THIS
lmno DO NOT LIKE
 pqr WANT THIS
...
```

From which I want to extract:

```
abc
ghijk
pqr
```

When I apply the following:

```
(Select-String -Path $infile -Pattern "([^ ]+) WANT THIS").Matches.Groups[1].Value >$outfile
```

It only returns the match for the first line:

```
abc
```

(adding -AllMatches did not change the behaviour)

Comment: Try `Select-String -path $infile -Pattern '^\s*(\S+) WANT THIS' -AllMatches | Foreach-Object {$_.Matches} | Foreach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value}`

Comment: Your solution works a lot better than mine - if you paste it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
Select-String -path $infile -Pattern '^\s*(\S+) WANT THIS' -AllMatches | Foreach-Object {$_.Matches} | Foreach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value} > $outfile
```

The `^\s*(\S+) WANT THIS` pattern will match

- `^` - start of a line
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars
- `WANT THIS` - a literal substring.

Now, `-AllMatches` will collect all matches, then, you need to iterate over all matches with `Foreach-Object {$_.Matches}` and access Group 1 values (with `Foreach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value}`), and then save the results to the output file.

Comment: Shouldn't one `Foreach-Object {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}` suffice? (+1)

Comment: Strange, I just checked with PSv5.1 and PSv6.1 and both returned proper results with `sls $infile -Pattern '^\s*(\S+).*want'|%{$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}`

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading the code, its matching them all, but only writing the value of the first match (doh!):

```
 (Select-String -Path $scriptfile -Pattern "([^ ]+)  WANT THIS").Matches.Groups.Value >$tmpfile
```

OTOH, it appears that the "captures" in the pattern output object **also contain the "non-captured" content!!!!**

Comment: This regex won't match `pqr WANT THIS` line, since it starts with a whitespace.